# How to login into a machine via putty using a script?

Tags: login, putty

In windows we have created a batch file to login into a machine via putty. On clicking the batch file it logins into that machine. Is it possible to create a script in ubuntu to do the same task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a launcher `server.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Server Name
Exec=ssh user@server.domain.com
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

and give it execution permissions.

Obviously you should put the real `user` and the real `server.domain.com` in the `Exec=` line.

To allow to choose the username, substitute the `Exec=` line with the following:

```
Exec=sh -c 'user=$(zenity --entry --title="Set username" --text="Username: " --entry-text="$USER"); if [ -n "$user" ]; then ssh $user@server.domain.com; else exit; fi'
```

Comment: What i want is, On clicking the script it should login into the machine.

Comment: karthick87: without entering a password? You'll need to use key-based authentication for that. Pass the `-i` option to `ssh` with the next argument the path to the private keyfile.

Answer (score 4):

Following up enzotib's answer: if you hardcode the login information in every script and file, it will make it more difficult to change it later if needed. A better solution would be creating a SSH configuration file with settings grouped under a host alias.

Instead or running:

```
ssh admin@meh.example.com -p 1234 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

you can create a `~/.ssh/config` file containing:

```
Host meh
    HostName meh.example.com
    User admin
    Port 1234
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Each of the settings below `meh` are optional, and when omitted, it will use defaults.

The command would then be:

```
ssh meh
```

You're allowed to override settings, the below command would login with username `super` using the keyfile `~/.ssh/other_key` and (provided by the config file) hostname `meh.example.com` on port 1234:

```
ssh super@meh -i ~/.ssh/other_key
```

Comment: +1, I too use config file, but opted for a quick solution in the answer.